# Central extension of the Discrete Heisenberg group $H_3(\Bbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I want to use the  Discrete Heisenberg group $(H_3(\Bbb Z),\times)$ as an example for a presentation on central extensions.

$H_3(\Bbb Z) = \begin{bmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}x,y,z\in \Bbb Z$

Now I have shown that the center of $H_3(\Bbb Z)$ is $Z = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&z\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

---

I want a short exact sequence:

$$I\hookrightarrow Z \hookrightarrow H_3(\Bbb Z) \twoheadrightarrow X\twoheadrightarrow I$$

Now for this to work, I need $X\cong H_3(\Bbb Z) / Z$ I believe, but I don't fully understand quotient groups apparently. Now I know that I can take this quotient group, since $Z$ is normal of course and I believe that we will get $$X= \begin{bmatrix}1&x&0\\0&1&y\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I can also see that $$Z^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}Z^{-1}=X$$

Where $Z^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-z\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

---

Does my guessed $X$ have $X\cong  H_3(\Bbb Z) / Z$

---

Can I let my maps be explicitly:

$$I\overset{\phi_1}{\hookrightarrow} Z \overset{\phi_2}{\hookrightarrow} H_3(\Bbb Z) \overset{\phi_3}{\twoheadrightarrow} X\overset{\phi_4}{\twoheadrightarrow} I$$

$$\phi_1:A\mapsto A$$$$\phi_2:A\mapsto A$$$$\phi_3:A\mapsto Z^{-1}A$$$$\phi_4:A\mapsto I$$

Comment: Your $X$ is not a subgroup of $H_3(\mathbb Z)$. Also, I don't know what you mean by «my maps» or what those things are, really!

Comment: Your $X$ is not closed under multiplication. Consider squaring the element with $x=y=1$ and taking a peek in the upper right corner.

Comment: @anon Crap. You are right. Is there even a central extension for this $H_3(\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: In a central extension, the quotient group need not be a subgroup of the group. Indeed, there *is* a cental extension, and it is precisely $0\to Z\to H_3(\mathbb Z)\to H_3(\mathbb Z)/Z\to 0$. You only need to find out what the structure of the quotient group $H_3(\mathbb Z)/Z$ is.

Comment: Your explanation of what the $\phi_i$ are leaves considerably more confused than what I was before!

Comment: Quotient groups don't have to be subgroups of the group you are taking the quotient of. For example $\Bbb Z$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ ($n>0$). Also, if that quotient was as subgroup in the manner you said, then the extension would split, but it doesn't.

Comment: How would one show that the above short exact sequence splits? By use of cohomology? Does $H^2(Z^2,Z)\neq0$ suffice? Can you refer me to the theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Z}[0]{\mathbb{Z}}$$X$ will be (isomorphic to) the group $\Z \times \Z$. Your maps will be
$$
\phi_{2} : z \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&0&z\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\phi_{3} : \begin{bmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \mapsto (x, y).
$$
The facts that $\phi_2$ is a homomorphism, and that $\phi_{3}$ is a (surjective) homomorphism follow from
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&x_1&z_1\\0&1&y_1\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}1&x_2&z_2\\0&1&y_2\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}1&x_1 + x_2&z_2 + x_1 y_2 + z_1\\0&1&y_1+y_2\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Moreover it is clear that 
$$
\ker(\phi_3)
=
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&z\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} : z \in \Z \right\}
=
\text{image of $\phi_2$},
$$
which gives you exactness.

---

Note that I'm taking the sequence as
$$I\overset{\phi_1}{\hookrightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \overset{\phi_2}{\hookrightarrow} H_3(\Bbb Z) \overset{\phi_3}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \overset{\phi_4}{\twoheadrightarrow} I,$$
and that there's only one choice for $\phi_1, \phi_4$.